# copy all xml attributes from 1 node to another

Tags: c#, xml

hi I have 2 xml nodes and I need to copy only all the attributes from the first into the other
`

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(somepath);
XmlNode node=doc.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "something", null);
System.Xml.XmlNodeList list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("tananana");
XmlNode node1= list[0];
Foreach (XmlAttribute att in node1.Attributes)
{
     System.Xml.XmlAttribute rAtt= doc.CreateAttribute(att.name ); //att.name is problem
     rAtt.Value=att.Value;  //att.value is problem
     node1.Attributes.Add(rAtt);
 }
```

Input test.xml:

```
<data>
  <tananana a1="1" a2="2"/>
  <tananana a3="3" a4="5"/>
  <tananana a1="5" a2="7"/>
</data>
```

Output:

```
<data>
  <something a1="1" a2="2" />
  <something a3="3" a4="5" />
  <something a1="5" a2="7" />
</data>
```

Comment: whats the exact problem? is att null? is name null ?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense cause `doc1` is unused.

Comment: i have put comments where the problem is

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: also at the end should add node1 to doc 1 but the problem is before that, where the comments are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input test.xml:

```
<data>
  <tananana a1="1" a2="2"/>
  <tananana a3="3" a4="5"/>
  <tananana a1="5" a2="7"/>
</data>
```

Output:

```
<data>
  <something a1="1" a2="2" />
  <something a3="3" a4="5" />
  <something a1="5" a2="7" />
</data>
```

Code:

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Xml.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var doc1 = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
            var doc2 = new XDocument(new XElement(doc1.Root.Name));

            doc2.Root.Add(doc1.Root
                .Elements("tananana")
                .Select(x => new XElement("something", x.Attributes())));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no the point is completely wrong. I'll add it below because of formatting

Comment: Input test.xml:

<data>
  <tananana a1="1" a2="2"/>
  <tananana a3="3" a4="5"/>
  <tananana a1="5" a2="7"/>
</data>
Output:

<data>
  <something a1="1" a2="2" /> <something a1="3" a2="5" /><something a1="5" a2="7" />
</data>

Comment: @Sonja added more LINQ because I love LINQ

Comment: I see I will check it now or tomorow morning but i like it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use XmlDocument then this would work. 
SetAttribute() copies value if an attribute exists in dstNode and creates new attribute otherwise

```
    protected void CopyAllAttributesValues(XmlElement srcNode, XmlElement dstNode)
    {
        foreach (XmlAttribute att in srcNode.Attributes)
        {
            dstNode.SetAttribute(att.LocalName, att.Value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Beside copying name and value, you should also consider what happens if an attribute is prefixed with a namespace, which the other answers so far would miss. Therefor just use the [CloneNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.clonenode?view=netframework-4.8) method, instead copying 'manually'.

```
XmlAttribute newAttribute = (XmlAttribute)sourceAttribute.CloneNode(true);
```